# Finding the Conditional Expectation of a Combined Discrete/Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

I'm considering a problem with a travelling salesman - every morning, he's given a list of $N$ people to sell goods to, with $N$ as a Poisson($30$) rv. He goes through each meeting and spends his time meeting with the clients at an exponential rate - $X$ is an exponential with rate parameter $n$ from $N=n$. I'm trying to find the expected amount of time he spends each day doing his job.

I know that

$$E[T] = \sum_{n\ge 0} E[X \mid N=n] P(N=n)$$

However, I'm not sure how to find $  E[X \mid N=n] $...

My first attempt made me believe that it would simply be  $n(\frac{1}{\lambda})$, but doing so would lead me to the unfortunate circumstances that $E[T] = 1$, which I know is false.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Why is it false? The more people he is given, the less time he spends with each of them - plus all quantities are chosen in such a way that the expected total time is constant 1. Sidenote: you are abusing notation here by using $X$ to denote both time spent with each client and total time spend with N clients.

Comment: @A.S. Yeah, definitely agree. Fixing that statement. It just seems wrong and outlandish, I guess, because for any mean value of $N$, the answer remains $1$.

Comment: Yeah, but since the expectation of an exponential random variable with parameter $x$ is $\frac1x$, one has $$E(X_k\mid N)=\frac1N,$$ which, together with the identity $$T=\sum_{k=1}^NX_k,$$ yields $$E(T\mid N)=\sum_{k=1}^NE(X_k\mid N)=1,$$ hence (a stronger form of) the result. (That is, if one explains carefully what happens when $N=0$...)

Comment: @Did Yeah, I agree, but then we end up with 

$$E[T] = \sum_{n\ge 0} E[X \mid N=n] P(N=n) = \sum_{n\ge 0} P(N=n) $$

Which, by the definition of any probability density function, is $1$, so $E[T] = 1$, which works out right, but implies that the salesperson talks to each person for $\frac{1}{30}$ of a minute on average! Is that reasonable?

Comment: Indeed the model in your question bears very little resemblance with any real life situation one can think of.